# How to check/uncheck Gridview check box for outside button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

How do I toggle the gridview check box from a button? I want to use Javascript only.

I am using below code for grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvWrkLogVW" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None" ShowHeader="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWorklog" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="The_Text" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to access the code gridview checkbox from external button

```
<asp:Button ID="btncheck" runat="server" Text="Check All" OnClientClick="SelectAll()" />
```

I am writing the below javascript but it is not working

```
 function SelectAll() {
     var gridViewControl = document.getElementById('<%= gvGetAllCircuits.ClientID %>');
         for (i = 0; i < gridViewControl.rows.length; i++) {
             if (gridViewControl.elements[1].type == "checkbox") {
                 gridViewControl.elements[1].checked = true;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: How does the output of aspx look ? Do you have a header in Gridview ? The problem could be your loop index

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
function SelectAll() {
        var gridViewControl = document.getElementById('<%= gvGetAllCircuits.ClientID %>');
        for (i = 0; i < gridViewControl.rows.length; i++) {

          //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
            for (i=1; i<gridViewControl.rows.length; i++)
            {
                //get the reference of first column - if you have a header
                cell = gridViewControl.rows[i].cells[0];

                //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
                {           
                    //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                    if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                    {
                    //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid
                        cell.childNodes[j].checked = "true";
                    }
                }
            }
       }
   }
```